# Android - Google Play Services - required to perform three actions on button click

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

In my android app, I am using google play services for my leaderboard scores.

Currently I am not adding any sign-in button. So on clicking Leaderboard button, these 3 actions should perform

1. Sign In to google play services
2. Submit scores to leaderboard
3. Open Google Play Services Leaderboard

Here is my code on button click

```
apiClient.connect();

if (apiClient != null && apiClient.isConnected()) {
    Log.v("GameLogic", "Display Leaderboard");
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(apiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_3_x_3), high_score_secs);
    startActivityForResult(
        Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(apiClient,
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_3_x_3)), 0);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Problem with Google Sign In. Please try again after sometime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

break;
```

Current Problem is:

Problem 01:
first time on button click, It connects to google play services but IF logic is not executed and Else Logic is Executed. ( Leaderboard is not displayed)

Problem 02:
from second time onwards, On button click both if and else logic is executed. Means leaderboard is displayed and at same time Else logic is executed.

Kindly Help. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how the API works, but some suggestions: **(a)** Nothing will make _one_ call to the above code execute _both_ branches of an `if` statement -- add `Log` messages either side of the `connect()` call to see if it's being called twice. **(b)** Does the `connect()` call wait until the connection has been made (or failed) or does it return immediately while the connection attempt is being attempted? (The above `Log` messages should tell you if you don't know). If the latter, you will need to wait in some fashion until it succeeds/fails.

Comment: @TripeHound , (b) it does not wait till it connects...

Comment: So that's probably the first problem. You are _initiating_ the connection/login, and then _immediately_ checking whether it is connected -- which of course it won't be. My first instinct would be to see if there is a callback or event that can be fired when the attempt has either worked/failed/timed-out (at which point you either display the leaderboard or the toast).